# What is the most efficient way to find the common intersection of given set of coordinates lies on x axis?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

For example :

```
(1,6) and (2,4) have (2,4) common. 
(2,4) and (3,6) have (3,4) common. 

There can be N numbers of coordinates and we have to find the common 
intersection point among all those coordinates.
```

Comment: What does it mean to say that two points have a third in common?

Comment: The third point lies in the range of those two given points.

Comment: What is the range of a point?  I think you have omitted the context for your question.

Comment: If you plot those two lines on x-axis then the third point is the common between those two points.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  There is no mention of any lines in your post...as I say, I think you have omitted a lot of necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intervals have a common intersection it should be $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the maximum value of all the left endpoints and $b$ is the minimum of all the  right sides.

In case that the $b$ happens to be less than $a$ there is no common intersection.

Of course a graph will always be helpful.